# How to redirect logged in user with url params?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-authentication

In my Django project I am trying to make the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` which is the home page to redirect to the Login in Page if user is not logged in however there is a user who is logged in I want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to become `http://127.0.0.1:8000/username/`

I have tried different answers but nothing specific lead to this answer:
Here is the login view after login:

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        user=self.request.user.username
        return f'/{user}/'
```

Here is the login urls:

```
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True,template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Here is the home views:

```
class home(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
```

Here is the app urls:

```
    path('<str:username>/', home.as_view(), name='home'),
```

**My question:**

How to redirect home page to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/username/` if user is logged in and if not to `login page`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`settings.LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-url) and [`settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url) so:

```py
class LoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    login_url='login'

    def get_success_url(self):
        user=self.request.user.username
        return reverse('home', args=(user))
```

In settings.py:

```py
LOGIN_URL='some_app_name:login' #Redirect to login page if not logged in.

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='some_app_name:home' #Redirect to home page after successful login
```

It defaults to `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` of settings.py if not specified in views.

> `Note:` It's not a good practice to name same your view with actual authentication view so it should be `MyLoginView` or anything you can give instead of actual view name.